# path of require module in node js work in windows but not in linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, path, require

i have this in my code

`var queries = require('./Queries.js');`

when start the node server in windows cmd is ok.

I clone the proyect in a linux ec2 server , but when i start the server 
not works

> Error: Cannot find module './Queries.js'

Comment: On Windows, filenames are case insensitive.  On Linux, files are case sensitive.  Are you sure your file is located in the proper location and is named `Queries.js` with that capitalization?

Comment: yes, that's was the problem,  thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making my comment into an answer since this seems to have been your issue:

On Windows, filenames are case insensitive. On Linux, files are case sensitive.  This is a common platform difference for anyone writing cross platform code for these two platforms.

So, make sure your file is located in the proper location and is named `Queries.js` with that exact capitalization.

I generally find it best to just never use mixed case (always all lowercase) in programming filenames and then you never have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Verify the path to 'Queries.js'

Case 1) Assuming you have NodeJS installed, the correct syntax you are looking for is below

```
var queries = require('querystring');
```

Case 2) :However if you are referencing code in another javascript file put something similar to the below at the top of current file.

```
require('./Queries.js'); //Queries.js is in the current directory
```

or

```
require('./path/to/Queries.js'); //The path to Queries.js
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this will work. This assumes its a module installed in the `node_modules`. If it's in the same directory, you suggestion would work if he did this instead: `var queries = require('./queries');`